# How to Create Paytm Check sum URL in order to create paytm merchant id

Tags: android, payment-gateway, paytm

Here I want to know paytm check sum URL.

I'm working a project in that to create merchant in Paytm it's asking Mobile Check Sum URL.
please can u any body help me from this.
if any body have developer support email or phone number kindly provide me those things

Answer (score 0):

Check this they have sample for all the application server side code
https://github.com/Paytm-Payments